# Calculate column value based on 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have 2 data frames, one has a Date column and other has 2 Dates column. Both has same index which is an ID.

My first question is to be sure if I am right, if I want to compute on both dataframes, the rows that has the same index will compute together ?

My second question is, I want to do a difference between the Date in df1 and one of the dates of the df2 like the following:

df1:

```
            Date1
 L-22     2015-03-12 
 L-15     2016-02-26
```

df2:

```
            Date2              Date3
 L-15     2016-01-11             NaT
 L-22        NaT              2017-01-08
```

I did something like this, and it gives error, ('NaTType' object has no attribute 'notnull')

```
      for i in df1.index:
         if df2['Date2'].ix[i].notnull():
            df1['Days_diff'] = df2['Date2'].sub(df1(train['Date1'], axis=0))
         elif df2['Date3'].ix[i].notnull():
            df1['Days_diff'] =df3['Date3'].sub(df1(train['Date1'], axis=0))
```

Any ideas ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) for replace `NaN` to values between columns:

```
dates = df2.Date2.combine_first(df2.Date3)
#alternative solution
#dates = df2.Date2.fillna(df2.Date3)

print (dates)
L-15   2016-01-11
L-22   2017-01-08
Name: Date2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and then substract values:

```
df1['Days_diff'] = dates.sub(df1['Date1'], axis=0)
print (df1)

          Date1  Days_diff
L-22 2015-03-12   668 days
L-15 2016-02-26   -46 days
```

Another solution is use `conditions`, but it seems output is same:

```
date2  = df2['Date2'].where(df2['Date2'].notnull()).sub(df1['Date1'], axis=0)
date3  = df2['Date3'].where(df2['Date3'].notnull()).sub(df1['Date1'], axis=0)
print (date2)
L-15   -46 days
L-22        NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

print (date3)
L-15        NaT
L-22   668 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

df1['Days_diff'] = date2.combine_first(date3)
print (df1)
          Date1  Days_diff
L-22 2015-03-12   668 days
L-15 2016-02-26   -46 days
```