# invalid type comparison error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been using this code:

```
df = df[df['A']>0]
df.loc[(df['A']<0), 'A'] = df['A'].median()
```

I am getting error invalid type comparison.

I would like to replace all values in the column A that are negative with median, mean or drop them.

Any explanation ?

EDIT: (continuation of [Calculate column value based on 2 dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901428/calculate-column-value-based-on-2-dataframes))

```
df1['A'] = dates.sub(df1['Date1'], axis=0)
print (df1)

          Date1     A
L-22 2015-03-12   668
L-15 2016-02-26   -46
```

Comment: I think all data are not numeric. So first try `df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)` and if problem `df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: it gives:float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp', it is the difference between dates in my previous question

Comment: can you add some data sample?

Comment: I've edited it and added the previous question, I would like to replace the -46 with median or mean or maybe drop it

Comment: A dtype is int64

Comment: Hmm, how works `df.loc[(df['A']<0), 'A'] = df['A'].median()` only? I remove `df = df[df['A']>0]`

Comment: and A is `df.A.dtype` `int` ?

Comment: yea...But the to_numeric fixed the problem somehow now

Comment: Yes, so there was some numeric data

Comment: no, for drop need only `df = df[df['A'] < 0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem some bad nonumeric value, so need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
```

For filtering need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['A'] < 0]
```